# Trying to get button to highlight on :hover correctly

Tags: css

I am trying to get a navigation style similar to the one on the Barnes & Noble home page. The problem I am having is that when I hover over the button it is shifted to the right instead of changing the background color of the entire background. I have a fiddle [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/ytF5v/16/) you can see what I mean I want it to fill up the space between both `|`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use padding and border-right to fill up the :hover space.

http://jsfiddle.net/ytF5v/14/

```
.topNavLinksButton {
    vertical-align:middle;
    line-height: 25px;
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
    padding: 0 0.5em;
    border-right: 1px solid #aaa;
}

.topNavLinksButton:last-of-type {
    border-style: none;
}

.topNavLinksButton:hover {
    background-color: #BDBDBD;
}
```

Comment: That is not what I need though I need the entire div background to be highlighted.

Comment: And if the border-right is too tall, change the line-height of each div to suit.

Comment: Still not right its close but  have a 50px tall main div that these links are stored in and vertical aligned to so there is a gap at the top and bottom I need it to fill the entire 50px not the size of just the line height I set. I want the dividers to be the same height as `|` but when I scroll over it needs to fill the entire square like in the fiddle I have

Comment: check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4Ms9j/1/) I think this what you are looking for

Comment: Close but still no cigar if you look at the barnes and noble website you will see exactly what I want